# Templates and lazy initialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a UIManager that manages a series of classes that inherit from a single UI class.  Currently, it works something like this, where the individual UIs are initialized lazily and are stored statically:

```
class UIManager
{

public:
   UIManager();            // Constructor
   virtual ~UIManager();   // Destructor


   template <typename T>
   T *getUI()
   {
      static T ui();       // Constructs T, stores result in ui when
                           // getUI<T>() is first called
      return &ui;    
   }
}
```

Called with:

```
getUI<NameEntryUI>()->activate();
```

or

```
getUI<MenuUI>()->render();
```

I am considering a design change that would allow me to have more than one player, hence more than one game window, hence more than one UIManager.  I want all my constructed ui objects to be cleaned up when the UIManager is deleted (currently, because the ui objects are static, they stick around until the program exits).

How can I rewrite the above to remove the ui objects when UIManager is killed?

======================================

Here is the solution I've implemented.  Early results are that it is working well.

Basically, I started with the idea suggested by Potatoswatter, which I liked because it was similar to an approach I had started then aborted because I didn't know about typeid(T).  I backported the code to use only C++98 features.  The key to the whole thing is typeid(T), which lets you map instantiated interfaces to their type in a consistent manner.

```
class UIManager
{
   typedef map<const char *, UserInterface *> UiMapType;
   typedef UiMapType::iterator UiIterator;

   map<const char *, UserInterface *> mUis;

public:
   UIManager();            // Constructor
   virtual ~UIManager()    // Destructor
   {
      // Clear out mUis
      for(UiIterator it = mUis.begin(); it != mUis.end(); it++) 
         delete it->second;

      mUis.clear();
   }

   template <typename T>
   T *getUI()
   {
      static const char *type = typeid(T).name();

      T *ui = static_cast<T *>(mUis[type]);
      if(!ui)
         ui = new T();

      mUis[type] = ui;

      return ui;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you only have storage space allocated for one UI element of each type. It's fundamentally impossible to keep that principle yet have any number of windows.

The quick and dirty solution would be to add a template argument for the window number. If it's a game, and you only have a limited number of players, you can have static storage for some predetermined number of windows.

```
template <typename T, int N>
T *getUI()
```

The approach of tying UI identity to the type system is fundamentally flawed, though, and I would recommend a more conventional approach using polymorphism and containers.

---

One way to identify the objects by type, yet store them dynamically, could look like

```
class UIManager {
    std::map< std::type_index, std::unique_ptr< UIBase > > elements;

    template< typename T >
    T & GetUI() { // Return reference because null is not an option.
        auto & p = elements[ typeid( T ) ];
        if ( ! p ) p.reset( new T );
        return dynamic_cast< T & >( * p );
    }
}
```

Note that this requires `UIBase` to have a virtual destructor, or the objects won't be terminated properly when you quit.

Comment: Storing `std::shared_ptr<void>` would mean the types don't need a common base class or a virtual destructor

Comment: @JonathanWakely Would be a bit of an abuse, though, since nothing is shared. Seriously, UI without polymorphism is lunacy. If there aren't virtual methods to draw and respond to clicks, at the very least, there is something very wrong with the program organization.

Comment: As I stated in my question, all my UI objects do inherit from a common parent (no lunacy here :-). I was trying to create just such a map, but didn't think to use unique_ptr. The only drawback is that unique_ptr is a C++11 item, and we have not yet fully embraced that.

Comment: @Watusimoto It also works without `unique_ptr`; you just have to `delete` manually. You could also use `auto_ptr`, which has been deprecated for C++11 in favor of `unique_ptr`; just remember to update when you upgrade.

Comment: Do not put `std::auto_ptr` in containers! _"instantiating a Standard
Library container with an `auto_ptr` results in undefined behavior."_  `std::unique_ptr` is OK.

Comment: If I'm sticking with c++98, and this is the sole source of pointers to the class, I may be able to get by with storing a raw pointer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ugh. For what it's worth, the exact usage suggested in this answer is well-defined for any reasonable implementation of `auto_ptr`, since it's never copied except in default-constructed state, so one could easily just roll his own `auto_ptr` and be fine.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't compile with G++, because the `pair` constructor used by `map::operator[]` tries to copy a `const auto_ptr` which fails, because `auto_ptr` is not CopyConstructible.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ohh, because the copy constructor does not allow const qualification of its argument. Then you're right. This case could use an `auto_ptr`-like class which asserts emptiness on copy, or some such. Or just use bare pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you clearly need multiple objects per type, let's simply store the objects in a `std::map<UIManager const*, T>`. To pull out a specific managed object, it is looked up in the map for the corresponding type. The tricky bit is later getting rid of the objects which is handled using a list of function objects:

```
class UIManager
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> d_cleaners;
    UIManager(UIManager const&) = delete;
    void operator=(UIManager const&) = delete;
public:
    UIManager();
    ~UIManager();

    template <typename T>
    T *getUI() {
        static std::map<UIManager const*, T> uis;
        typename std::map<UIManager const*, T>::iterator it = uis.find(this);
        if (it == uis.end()) {
            it = uis.insert(std::make_pair(this, T())).first;
            this->d_cleaner.push_back([it, &uis](){ uis.erase(it); });
        }
        return &(it->second);   
    }
};
```

The respective `getUI()` function stores a map mapping the address of the `UIManager`, i.e., `this`, to the corresponding object. If there is no such mapping, a new mapping is inserted. In addition, to make sure objects are cleaned up, a cleaner function is registered with `this`, simply `erase()` in the iterator just obtained from the corresponding map. The code is untested but something along those lines should work.

Comment: If the UI objects are polymorphic, as is usual practice, there should be a virtual function to perform visual clean-up. (It would be done by the destructor, but they should be exception-safe.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I don't understand what your point is! Yes, things can be done differently but that seems to be besides the point. There is certainly some advantage of getting hold of the correct type using `getUI<T>()`: you could just call member functions directly.

Comment: The advantage of avoiding virtual dispatch is performance, but that simply doesn't count in this context.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Surely you meant to write "One advantage" as there are others. The fact that the correct type is statically known and it doesn't need any casting is another advantage.

Comment: I think it's the only advantage. You can still use a polymorphic object as if it weren't; polymorphism doesn't stop you from statically knowing anything.

Comment: I suppose the cleanup would occur in ~UIManager() where there would be code that cycles through the d_cleaners and deletes things.  The mapping in the static uis map would stick around forever, which, while messy, would not be a practical problem as long as the number of UIManagers created is sane, and as long as addresses don't get reused (a seemingly unlikely problem I've experienced elsewhere).

Comment: @Watusimoto: Yes, the destructor needs to call each function to remove the respective entry.

Comment: @Watusimoto Depends what cleanup means. Avoid letting a destructor throw, because such will turn proper exception processing into sudden termination. Pick a safe time to finalize first. (This was also the point of my frist comment.)